# Screw Modifier - how to change axis dynamically?

Tags: modeling, mathematics, screw-modifier

[image]I'm trying to use a screw function to create a spiraling object with an axis that changes over distance. In the attached photo I have a screw with a uniform axis, but I would like the spiral of the screw to follow the geometry of the "egg," so the screw has a small axis at the bottom/top of the egg, and widest axis in the center of the egg. The egg is a UV sphere that has been scaled in the Z axis by 1.5x. I appreciate any recommendations for how to approach this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add *Sphere* and add *Spherical Spiral* (you have to enable addon **Extra Curve** for that).

[image]

Parent *Spiral* to *Sphere*.
In Object mode scale Sphere to egg shape.
Rotate Spiral.

[image]